# ScrollViewer width to be narrower

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I want to override the width of the scroll bar of ScrollViewer in WPF.  I manage to widen its width but when I tried to make it slimmer it didn't work.  It seems that it has a minimum width that can't be overridden.  Below is the code that I have.

Why is the code below does not work to make the width of the scrollbar slimmer?

Thanks

```
           <ScrollViewer.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ScrollViewer.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried to modify the ColumnWidth of the Scrollbar (Vertical) from the Control Template. Template you can take it from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-styles-and-templates. Not sure if this helps you are not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the template.

Place the editor cursor inside the `ScrollViewer` tag and then in your properties window go to "Miscellaneous -> Template", click the little rectangle to the right and select "Convert to New Resource" from the popup menu:

[image]

That will create a new template containing, among other things, a scrollbar named `PART_VerticalScrollBar`. Put the cursor over that scrollbar tag and repeat the above to template that out as well, this will create a control template that starts like this:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollBarControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
```

Now set `MaxWidth=10` (or whatever on that Grid element).

The only other problem you may encounter is that if you make it too small then the up/down arrows on the scrollbar buttons might disappear, that's because their default template places a margin around their path:

```
<Path x:Name="ArrowTop" Data="M0,4C0,4 ..etc ... " Fill="#FF606060" Margin="3,4,3,3" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

This can be easily solved by removing that margin setting and/or replacing the path altogether with something else.